# Why C# library for SengGrid API-v3 is on fictional email to SetFrom method get bad requests?

Tags: c#, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am using Senddrid C# library provided by SendGrid to send messages. I have dynamic template. On user click it sends emails with dynamic fields.

So problem is what by some means I cannot use fictional email for that I must use real/activated email. Just in case inputs are valid or got from appseting.js and are also valid. Its problem with "SetFrom" method. No problems with template id or app_key

! Real email - I mean email what I could log-in and send messages for example
! Fake email - to use as stub. for example `no-reply@gmail.com`

```
    private async Task mySendEmail(string toAddress, string templateId, JObject dynamicTemplateData, string? toWhome = null, string? setFromEmail = null, string? setFromName = null)
    {
        if (setFromEmail is null)
            setFromEmail = sendGridConfig.SendGridApiFrom;

        if (setFromName is null)
            setFromName = sendGridConfig.SendGridApiFromDisplayName;

       // var foo = sendGridConfig.SendGridApiKey;
        var client = new SendGridClient(sendGridConfig.SendGridApiKey);
        var msg = new SendGridMessage();

        
        msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(toAddress, toWhome));
        //msg.SetFrom("my-real-email@gmail.com", setFromName); // if using real email it works
        msg.SetFrom(new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User 0")); // fictional email have bad requests
        msg.SetTemplateData(dynamicTemplateData);
        msg.SetTemplateId(templateId);

       

        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg); // Bad request


    }
```

The output of the result

```
{"from":{"name":"Example User 0","email":"test@example.com"},"personalizations":[{"to":[{"name":"Stone Ocean","email":"count_zero@inbox.lv"}],"dynamic_template_data":{"url":"CUCUMBER@INBOX.LV","password":"TEREMOK"}}],"template_id":"d-2f393a3c5ca7451ea856fc1acadf0bd7"}
Forbidden
{"errors":[{"message":"The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved. Visit https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/ to see the Sender Identity requirements","field":"from","help":null}]}
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl
Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
X-No-CORS-Reason: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=600; includeSubDomains
Date: Thu, 24 Nov 2022 07:37:40 GMT
Server: nginx
```

Any ideas why SetFrom need real email not fictional and how to avoid it?

Comment: "by some means I cannot use fictional email" - what do you mean? What goes wrong when you use the example.com email address? Have you tried multiple kinds of fictional email addresses?

Comment: @JonSkeet Here are example of result output/ I run it on different project/ https://imgur.com/V9U16cC

Comment: Please put the details in the question, as *text* rather than as an image.

Comment: @JonSkeet Putted details in the question

Comment: You should not use a "faux"-from anyway. Chances are very slim to non-existing the e-mails would actual get delivered - Sendgrid even dedicated an [article](https://sendgrid.com/blog/dont-send-email-from-domains-you-dont-control/) to this practice

Comment: Okay, so did you visit the link in the output? Doesn't that answer your question? "To ensure our customers maintain the best possible sender reputations and to uphold legitimate sending behavior, we require customers to verify their Sender Identities." If you've read that and you understand it, what more are you asking about in this question?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank for advice. Yeap the email sand from must be verified. I first time working with SendGrid and other mail sending services so for me this was strange what email must be verified or you can not send from it. I am Derp. Derp. Derp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According SendGrid the sender email(email what is sent FROM) must be verified by SendGrid to send email from it. Otherwise request throws error. Why this [click](https://sendgrid.com/blog/dont-send-email-from-domains-you-dont-control/)